# How will the probability change with new restriction(Red Zone)

Tags: options

[image: No restriction]

If I sold an OTM put option(-16 delta) the **probability of touching the short put strike is 32%**(i.e 2*16). *The risk profile is represented by the picture above.*

[image: Red Zone-Restriction]

How can I calculate the **new probability of touching** the short put strike given that price can not touch +16 delta(*1 standard deviation above current price*) before the short put is touched? *The picture above shows the risk graph of the put combined with the area of the restriction(red zone)*.

**EDIT:** I used ***2x[delta of the option]*** for the first case, which is a rough estimate for the ***probability of touch***.

Comment: It’s well past a day and there is no answer or comment. I have **2 ideas** of what the answer to my question could be but I am not sure if any of the 2 is correct. *But first let **A** represent the event that short put strike is touched.* *Let **B** be the probability of touching the red zone(at +16 delta).*

Comment: **1st Idea:** P(A and B’)=2*0.16*(1-2*0.16)=21.76% The problem with this idea is the **B’ or not touch B** because price can touch A and still touch B sometime before expiration. *Not sure if **B’** is used correctly(Should be no touch till A is hit).*

Comment: **2nd Idea:** Is to use symmetry. *There is an equal chance for price to touch the short put strike and the +16 delta(Red zone boundary).* If that’s the case the new probability of touch(theoretical) is: **0.5*2*0.16=16%**

Comment: This might be better suited for https://quant.stackexchange.com. There's not a simple probability  that can be computed without some other inputs (and note that the probability based on Delta is a very rough estimate)

Comment: @D Stanley what other inputs are required? Yeah I need an estimate not the exact value.

Comment: The time to maturity of the option and the volatility (usually implied from option prices).

Comment: @D Stanley Got that. But when the probability of touch was calculated initially those where not needed, only delta was(to get a rough estimate). Why exactly are those new inputs needed for a slight change of the question?

Comment: Long story short - you have to know how much time is left and how volatile the stock is to know the probability of the barrier being reached. The Delta you were given was also calculated using those inputs.

Comment: Also, a nitpick, but the delta is not an approximation of the probability of _touch_, but the probability of _ending_ below the strike. The stock can go below the strike but come back and still expire OTM. With a knock-out, the upper barrier only has to be touched _once_ for the option to be cancelled.

Comment: @D Stanley Yeah that’s why I used the approximate formulae: *2*delta of option= probability of touch* I know delta itself is approximate for probability of expiring ITM.

Comment: @D Stanley *I don’t know if you understand my last comment?*

Comment: I've never seen that approximation for "probability of touch" so if you're looking for an answer base don that I won't be of much more help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, much appreciated. @D Stanley